# Access Denied: You may only modify your own profile, unless you are an administrator

Tags: 2007, user-profile

I am getting Accessdenied error. while setting value to user profile property. This method in my custom web service. running on System Account application pool identity.

Execption:

```
***

Before spSiteUserToken.SystemAccount.UserToken; 
     After spSiteUserToken.SystemAccount.UserToken; 
     Inside using (SPSite spSite 
     After HttpContext.Current = null; 
     Access Denied: You may only modify your own profile, unless you are an administrator. STACKTRACE :   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileValueCollection.CheckUpdatePermissions() 
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileValueCollection.set_Value(Object value) 
     at SharePoint.Webservices.SharePointCustomerManagement.<>c__DisplayClass16.<UpdateUserInUserProfiles>b__12() 
      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevatedWrapper(Object state) 
      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2() 
      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) 
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param) 
      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) 
       at SharePoint.Webservices.SharePointCustomerManagement.UpdateUserInUserProfiles(Customer c, String personalSiteUrl, String siteCollectionUrl)
```

---

```
 private void UpdateUserInUserProfiles(Customer c, string personalSiteUrl, string siteCollectionUrl)
    {
        SPSite mySites = null;
        SPWeb userPersonalSite = null;
        HttpContext saved = HttpContext.Current;

        try
        {
            SPUserToken res = null;
            SPSite spSiteUserToken = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl);
            bool oldCatchAccessDeniedException = spSiteUserToken.CatchAccessDeniedException;
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Before spSiteUserToken.SystemAccount.UserToken;");
                spSiteUserToken.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
               // res = spSiteUserToken.SystemAccount.UserToken;
                res = GetSystemToken(spSiteUserToken);
                Debug.WriteLine("After spSiteUserToken.SystemAccount.UserToken;");
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                   using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl, res))
                   {
                         Debug.WriteLine("Inside using (SPSite spSite");
                         Office.ServerContext serverContext =
                         Office.ServerContext.GetContext(spSite);

                         UserProfileManager pmManager =
                         new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
                         string strUserName = _providerName +
                         c.CustomerNumber;
                         spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                         HttpContext.Current = null;
                         Debug.WriteLine("After HttpContext.Current = null;");
                         if (!pmManager.UserExists(strUserName))
                         {
                            UserProfile newUser1 =
                            pmManager.CreateUserProfile(strUserName);
                            UserProfile newUser =
                            pmManager.GetUserProfile(strUserName);
                            newUser["PreferredName"].Value = c.FullName;
                            newUser["FirstName"].Value = c.FirstName;
                            newUser["LastName"].Value = c.LastName;
                            newUser["WorkEmail"].Value = c.Email;
                            newUser.Commit();
                                                               _sbAuditTrail.Append("User profile updated in ProfileDatabase: " + siteCollectionUrl + " : ");
                       }
                       else
                       {
                            UserProfile updateUser =pmManager.GetUserProfile(strUserName);
                            updateUser["PreferredName"].Value = c.FullName;
                            updateUser["FirstName"].Value = c.FirstName;
                            updateUser["LastName"].Value = c.LastName;
                            updateUser["WorkEmail"].Value = c.Email;
                            updateUser.Commit();
                                                                                          _sbAuditTrail.Append("User profile updated in ProfileDatabase: " + siteCollectionUrl + " : ");
                       }
                       spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                   }
               });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(GetErrorMessage(ex));                    
            }
            finally
            {
                spSiteUserToken.CatchAccessDeniedException = oldCatchAccessDeniedException;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            _errorCount = _errorCount + 1;
            _sbErrors.Append(GetErrorMessage(ex));
            LogMessage("Exception Occured in UpdateUserInUserProfiles: " + GetErrorMessage(ex), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
             HttpContext.Current = saved;

            if (userPersonalSite != null)
            {
                userPersonalSite.Close();
            }

            if (mySites != null)
            {
                mySites.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by moving  `HttpContext.Current = null;` to top of `Office.ServerContext serverContext = Office.ServerContext.GetContext(spSite);`

Now it is working good.

Answer (score 0):

Is the account a UPA Administrator? Check the settings on the Service Application.